# Why is this program assigning a weird number to the variable j?

Tags: c, for-loop, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm studying C with the Kernighan & Ritchie 2nd Ed. book and I'm currently at chapter 2. The fifth exercise in this chapter asks for the reader to "Write the function any(s1,s2), which returns the first location in a string s1 where any character from the string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 contains no characters from s2."

I did my program, but I also went looking for others answers the see other people's approach to the problem. I came across this program found at this [link](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_2.5_any.html).

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int mgetline(char line[],int maxline);
int any(char s1[],char s2[]);

int main(void)
{
    char s1[MAXLINE],s2[MAXLINE];
    int val;
    
    /* Give the first string s1 */
    
    mgetline(s1,MAXLINE);
    
    /* Give the second string s2 */

    mgetline(s2,MAXLINE);

    val = any(s1,s2);

    printf("%d",val);

    return 0;
}

int mgetline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i)
        s[i]=c;

    if(c=='\n')
        s[i++]=c;
    s[i]='\0';
}

int any(char s1[],char s2[])
{
    int i, j, check_next_char;

    check_next_char = 1;

    for(i = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && (check_next_char);) 
    {
        // iterate through s2 while trying to find matching character from s1
        for(j = 0; s2[j] != '\0' && (s1[i] != s2[j]); ++j) 
            ; // continue

        if(s2[j] == '\0') {
            check_next_char=1;
            i++; // go for the next char in s1
        }
        else
            check_next_char=0; // match found
    }

    if(s1[i] == '\0')
        return -1;
    else
        return i;
}
```

The issue is at the function **any**. Whenever I write strings that don't share any character the variable j gets assigned the value of 10 in the first loop, and then some random numbers as the loop proceeds. I can't find the issue with the code. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Did you try to run it in a debugger and step through? That would reveal where these numbers are coming from

Comment: You intended to retain newlines ? I ask because as written that will always be  a match if nothing else was.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did run it in a debugger, that's how I noticed the weird values attributed to the j variable.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't understand what you meant, could you elaborate further?

Comment: Your `mgetline` is specifically handling the addition of the newline character in the end, while the loop above it is specifically excluding it. Which makes it look like some kind of patch which should not be there.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said: ex: s1 =`abcd\n` , s2 = `efgh\n` . By retaining newline chars, the newline char is not zero, and *will* match and thus your `any` function will *never* return `-1`. Belaying that, forget `j` for a moment. Is your code actually producing the output for given input you intended? For the inputs I just showed the result would print `4`.

Comment: @Silk - Where is this _loop_ you are talking about?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The mgetline function was provided by the authors in the book. It was made for old computers that ran the terminal in real time, processing the inputs as they were typed, or so I have read. The line you mentioned just adds the new line character to the string if the user types it, it doesn't cause any issues. The loop is set to break if the user types the newline because that means that the current string is over, but the characters must be added to it, nonetheless.

Comment: The real issue happens inside the **any** function, where the second loop begins. If the strings don't match, it just does not initialize j as 0.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand what you are saying now, you are right. It happens just as you say. Thanks a lot for the help. I actually debugged it many times but was blind to the \n character.
I was biased by my code, which is similar to the one I posted, but did not retain the \n character.

Comment: @WhozCraig This is my first post here, how do I set your comment as the right answer?

Comment: There is a standard `string.h` function, [strpbrk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strpbrk.html). Of course, if you are trying to learn how to do it yourself, this is not useful.

Comment: You cannot mark a comment as an answer, because it is not an answer. @WhozCraig needs to post an answer for you to mark. Please take the [tour] (again). -- But it might not be worth an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The new line char, '\n', is also considered as a character to be compared. According to your program, each string should have the new line char and it is matched at the end of the first string in any way. I fixed the problem by commenting out these two lines.

```
    //if(c=='\n')
    //   s[i++]=c;
```

This is the program updated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int mgetline(char line[],int maxline);
int any(char s1[],char s2[]);

int main(void)
{
    char s1[MAXLINE],s2[MAXLINE];
    int val;
    
    /* Give the first string s1 */
    
    mgetline(s1,MAXLINE);
    
    /* Give the second string s2 */

    mgetline(s2,MAXLINE);

    val = any(s1,s2);

    printf("%d",val);

    return 0;
}

int mgetline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i)
        s[i]=c;

    //if(c=='\n')
    //   s[i++]=c;

    s[i]='\0';      
}

int any(char s1[],char s2[])
{
    int i, j, check_next_char;

    check_next_char = 1;

    for(i = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && (check_next_char);) 
    {
        // iterate through s2 while trying to find matching character from s1
        for(j = 0; s2[j] != '\0' && (s1[i] != s2[j]); ++j) 
            ; // continue

        if(s2[j] == '\0') {
            check_next_char=1;
            i++; // go for the next char in s1
        }
        else
            check_next_char=0; // match found
    }

    if(s1[i] == '\0')
        return -1;
    else
        return i;
}
```